# Can`t use git pull on directory after copy to external hdd

Tags: 18.04, external-hdd, git

I'm facing a strange problem.
I've formatted a external disk partition as exFat. then I've copied my development projects from ext4 hdd into this partition using nautilus.

Now when I tried to use git pull on  the copied partition I've received a error message: `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:`

could someone explain me what am I missing?

---

I've installed small ssd in two ubuntu machines and an old macbook. Also I bought a 2Tb external hdd to concentrate my development projects and media files.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reasos, but one of them is that `exfat` is case insensitive.

This means that file named `Makefile` is converted to `makefile`, etc.

git treats this as a change. Moving git repos to case insensitive file systems is a bad idea in general.

Other issues may be with symlinks, etc.

Most of Linux sources won't build after this kind of move.

You can make an HFS+ (or HFS if macbook is too old for HFS+) partition on your HDD for exchange with Macbook. But I have no experience with that. HFS(+) is OK for git and development. It is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks.
I've tried also with NTFS, that is supposed to be a case-sensitive format, but it is also given me some non-visible changes. :(

Comment: ntfs is insensitive as well. It has case sensitive capabilities but they are traditionally disabled there for compatibility with FAT. Use linux filesystems.

Comment: I updated the question explaining the reason I'm trying to used those file system. I need also allow a macbook to access the git repositories.

Comment: Macbook's HFS+ is case sensitive.

Comment: but can I read and write HFS+ with ubuntu too?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can format it to HFS or HFS+ using gparted on Ubuntu. It is fully supported by Linux.

Comment: You can debug if it's a filesystem problem formatting the external partition to ext4 and instead of copying the folder using Nautilus, use rsync with the `-avzh` options.